# What are SVN entries?

Tags: svn

For example, what does something like this mean?

xxx.com/templates/default/image/.svn/entries:http://svn174.xxx.com:8174/svn/project

I noticed this in code and would like to know what it is and if anything happens if I remove it from the code.

Comment: Can you show the code in question?  It makes it hard to determine the effects of removing this from the code without seeing the code.

Comment: I found this by using the shell command and searching files for xxx.com. What is an svn entries file anyway? Can I get rid of it or will it affect my website?

Answer (score 0):

It almost looks like the notation subversion uses when there are conflicts between files that can't be automatically merged.

If so you might have a larger problem.  Resolving those conflicts manually through svn should have cleaned everything up and left you with your files without any of these dangling references.  If they are still hanging around it suggests that you have (or had...) merge collisions that were not properly resolved, and someone forced svn through anyway with pieces of code erroneously missing or incorrectly resolved.

Edit from comment:  Subversion (svn) is used to track changes to code while it's under development.  It's not a part of the code, nor should the files be present on a production system (like a public web server).  But while it's tempting to say that it should therefore be safe to just delete the .svn/entries file and the lines in the code and forget all about it, none of those things should be there in the first place, so you really want to find out how they got there and what else you're missing.

Comment: I found this by using the shell command and searching files for xxx.com. What is an svn entries file anyway? Can I get rid of it or will it affect my website?

Comment: Updated answer based on comment

Comment: If I am missing something, then what can I change to test if something is missing?

Comment: Do you have access to the subversion repository?

Comment: No. I hired a developer and I just want to make sure I have all the files. So what should I change and see if the website is still running or not? This way I can know if I have everything on my server.

Comment: That's too open-ended a question to be able to answer easily.  If you don't have access to the old repository, though, one of the first things to do is get a new one started right away.  Your developer should understand version control and be able to get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In the old (ie pre 1.7) versions of SVN, your working copy uses a hidden directory called `.svn` that contains a bit of metadata about the repository, including things like properties and the last-committed file data. You get one of these .svn directories in every directory on your disk that is stored in your SVN repository. 
The reason for having these is so when you make some operations on your SVN working copy, it doesn't always have to hit the repository over the network.

What you're looking at looks like some of this metadata. If you remove it from the disk you will lose the linkage between the working copy and the repository for those files. You'll have to perform a `svn cleanup`, or worse-case, checkout a fresh working copy and copy your file over the top of it.

If you're unsure about this, get your svn admin to advise you.

Comment: That makes sense. But I'm confused by one thing where you said if I remove it from the disk I will lose the linkage between the working copy and the repository. So right now is my website dependent on third party website? My website is currently running right now, but I do not have the full code?